# Application works after closing and restarting

Tags: windows, windows-xp, client-server

I am working with an old Borland 1999 C++ client\server application that I don't have the source code to... unfortunately there is no vendor support or alternative this app.

This is a bit of a head scratchier but the application doesn't work when first opened. If the application is closed and reopened, it works great. If around 2 minutes have expired since the application was previously opened... it goes back to not working again.

The issue is easy to reproduce but I'm not really sure what the next steps should be to get to root cause.

Some of my theories include a DLL that may not be loading on first launch, a TCP/IP port that gets initiated (and dies after 2 minutes), or perhaps a timing issue where a thread tries to access something before a library is loaded...

Any ideas would be appreciated. This is for a very noble cause... this application ensures quality control for 12 ounce glass bottles so that you can enjoy a cold beer.

Answer (score 0):

It could be an application compatibility setting. There are a few things that you can try. I have used all of these to get legacy applications to work. Try one at a time to see if any of them help.

[Data execution prevention:](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-au/windows-vista/data-execution-prevention-frequently-asked-questions)
Right Click on my Computer, choose Properties, Advanced Tab, Performance Settings button. In the Performance Options window choose Data Execution Tab.  Click add, then select the executable in the dialog that pops up. Click ok.
There is more information in [this MS article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/875352) with a few more options to try. But I have only ever needed to use the setting above.

[Application compatibility mode](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb456979.aspx): (the link is old but still relevant)
Right click on your executable, choose properties, compatibility Tab, Tick run this program in compatibility mode for.
Choose the mode you want. All the apps I needed to use this for worked with Windows XP Sp3 mode.

[Windows firewall](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/875356): Turn it off for troubleshooting. If your app works, then add an exclusion.

[UAC: Turn off UAC](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/turn-user-account-control-on-off#1TC=windows-7). I know this is not in Windows XP, but is useful for later versions of windows.
Control Panel, User Accounts, Change user account Settings. Move the slider all the way down. Press OK.

You might need to do these on both the client PC and the server.